# javascrip - function not recognized in the callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a Cordova application with JQuery.

In my index.js I have the following codes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("ready");

   // Initialize the app
   app.initialize();

});

// Define the app
var app = {
    // Initialize the app    
    initialize: function() {
       // deviceready Event Handler
      $(document).on('deviceready', function() {
         console.log("Device is ready!");

         // 'deviceready' is an DOM element on the Html page.
         this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
      });
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
   receivedEvent: function(id) {
      var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
      var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
      var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

      listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
      receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
   },

...
}
```

When I ran the script in Cordova, it threw an error:

```
TypeError: this.receivedEvent is not a function
```

It seems that the "this" object is not properly referenced as app.

Comment: the `this` inside the `$(document).on(..` will be pointing to the `window` object and not to `app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do the same as below.

```
initialize: function() {
   // deviceready Event Handler
  var self = this
  $(document).on('deviceready', function() {
     console.log("Device is ready!");

     // 'deviceready' is an DOM element on the Html page.
     self.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `this` is different inside the `deviceready` handler function. Use an arrow function:

```
$(document).on("deviceready", () => {...});
```

Or just avoid initializing an event listener inside a function - it's better to do them all at once at the top of your script.

Comment: Thanks, This works. Just wondering why the arrow function works?

Comment: Because the arrow function inherits its `this` binding, unlike normal functions.

Comment: Hi @Jack. I am sorry I would have accepted your answer as correct. However, just realized the arrow function did not work in Cordova when running the emulator on Android. It worked on the browser environment at the first place though.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to move the device ready logic into JQuery document onReady function?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
 const myObject = {
      initialize: function() {
        // deviceready Event Handler
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
      console.log("Device is ready!");

      // 'deviceready' is a DOM element on the HTML page.
      this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    });
  },

  receivedEvent: function(event) {
    // Your logic for handling the 'deviceready' event
    console.log(`Received event: ${event}`);
  }
};

// Call the initialize function to start the process
myObject.initialize();
```